Type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'
I use the useContext method in my React Layout component and get this error that Type 'StringConstructor' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
I wrote Layout Component  such as :
 function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

const layoutcontext = useContext(LayoutContext);  

return (
 <div id="company-info-wraper" className="d-none d-lg-block">
     <div className=" text-center">
         <p id="company-name">{layoutcontext.Organization} </p>
         <p id="package-name" style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}> {layoutcontext.Name } </p>
         <p id="package-code">({layoutcontext.Code }) ( {layoutcontext.Version })</p>
     </div>
 </div>

)
}

LayoutContext :
import { createContext } from "react";
    
    const LayoutContext = createContext({
    
        Organization: String,
        Name: String,
        Code: String,
        Version: String
    });
export default LayoutContext;

What is the problem? How can I fix this?

The problem lies in your usage of createContext().
This code:
const LayoutContext = createContext({
        Organization: String,
        Name: String,
        Code: String,
        Version: String
});

is assigning the String constructor as the default value for all your fields. If you do not have a default value, simply pass null to your createContext(null)
If you're using TypeScript and intending to pass the types of the values the context can hold, then define the types in this way:
import { createContext } from "react";

type LayoutContextType= {
  organization: string;
  name: string;
  code: string;
  version: string;
};

const LayoutContext = createContext<LayoutContextType | null>(null);

export default LayoutContext;

The actual value will be passed through the LayoutContext.Provider's value prop when wrapping your components.
References:
https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext
https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/
